# Split string to array from a json file in nifi jolt

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I am trying to transform a string into an array from a JSON using a JOLT transformation processor in nifi
How can I do this?

I am trying to transform a string into an array from

```json
{
  "_source": {
    "users": {
      "attributes": {
        "organization": {
          "display": "org1",
          "objectGUID": "7",
          "attributes": {
            "distinguishedName": "ou=org1,OU=BU"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and transform it into this

```json
{
  "_source": {
    "users": {
      "attributes": {
        "organization": {
        "0" : {
             "display": "org1",
             "objectGUID": "7",
            "attributes": {
              "distinguishedName": "ou=org1,OU=BU"
             }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Sometimes the input json is already transformed into an array and it looks like this

```json
{
  "_source": {
    "users": {
      "attributes": {
        "organization": {
        "0" : {
             "display": "org1",
             "objectGUID": "7",
            "attributes": {
              "distinguishedName": "ou=org1,OU=BU"
             }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

with the "0" tag added. So in this case, the tag must not be added again.
Sometimes I can have multiple elements like this

```json
{
  "_source": {
    "users": {
      "attributes": {
        "organization": {
        "0" : {
             "display": "org1",
             "objectGUID": "7",
            "attributes": {
              "distinguishedName": "ou=org1,OU=BU"
             }
          },
        "1" : {
             "display": "org1",
             "objectGUID": "7",
            "attributes": {
              "distinguishedName": "ou=org1,OU=BU"
             }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Again this should remain unchanged.

So I want to apply the transformation only if the "0" tag is not there. otherwise leave it as it is.

How can I do this?

Comment: Hi Vio, welcome to SO. I couldn't understand what you have meant by `string`

Comment: What if the `1` tagged object already exists? Do we need to add the upcoming one tagged `2`?

Comment: No. Only 0 if it is not there.
The point is that in another processor I have all this fields users.attributes.organization.0.display, users.attributes.organization.1.display , users.attributes.organization.2.display concatenated into a list. 
But sometimes the organizations arrives in this format (without "0") users.attributes.organization.display  and to take it also in consideration I have to formatted it to look the same (users.attributes.organization.0.display) and put it in the list. 
So the change has to be reflected only if 0 is missing, otherwise the json should remain the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use such a **shift** transformation spec which adds an extra object wrapper as desired

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": { // level of "_source"
        "*": { // level of "users"
          "*": { // level of "attributes"
            "*": "&3.&2.&1.&.0" // level of "organization"
                                // identifiers with ampersands copies the values of the outer keys each from their respective levels
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

**Edit** : Based on your last edit and comments you can use the following spec having conditional logic

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": {
              "0": "&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
              "*": "&4.&3.&2.&1.0.&"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: it works, the organization tag has "0" tag added. 
But sometimes the "0" tag is added from the beginning and with this is added again. 
how to check if the "0" tag is already added and only if not to add it

Comment: and sometimes I have
``` 
{
  "_source": {
    "users": {
      "attributes": {
        "organization": {
        "0" : {
             "display": "org1",
             "objectGUID": "7",
            "attributes": {
              "distinguishedName": "ou=org1,OU=BU"
             }
          },
         "1" : {
             "display": "org1",
             "objectGUID": "7",
            "attributes": {
              "distinguishedName": "ou=org1,OU=BU"
             }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Vio What you expect based on what inputs are unclear. Please, edit the question(rather than commenting) by toggling the `Edit` button just below the question to show case by case what you have as inputs and what you expect as output.

Comment: I changed my question so it has also this information. Thanks!